# a triggers script doesn't work properly

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I have three tables in my database :

> ```
> Room (num PK, seats, reservation price)
> Reservation (num PK, client id FK Client(id), room number FK Room(num), reservation date)
> Client (id PK, name)
> ```

I want before making a reservation, we check if the room is not taken using triggers.

this is the script I tried :

```
CREATE TRIGGER Verify_room_taken ON reservation
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
    BEGIN
        IF EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM reservation
                    WHERE [room number] = (SELECT [room number] FROM INSERTED)
                    AND [reservation date] = (SELECT [reservation date] FROM INSERTED))
        ROLLBACK TRAN
    END
```

But this script doesn't work properly, when I add a reservation on a different date and different room it doesn't make the changes I have made because of the cursor.

This is the code I tried in the second time :

```
ALTER TRIGGER Verifier_chambre_prise ON reservation
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
    BEGIN
        IF NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM reservation
                    WHERE [n° de chambre] = (SELECT [n° de chambre] FROM INSERTED)
                    AND [date de réservation] = (SELECT [date de réservation] FROM INSERTED))
            INSERT INTO reservation  SELECT * FROM INSERTED
    END
```

Comment: Why not just placed a `UNIQUE` constraint on `[room number],[reservation date]`? Also, your trigger is broken in at least 2 ways if a multi-row `INSERT` is performed.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I cant use the UNIQUE constraint because the exercise I'm trying to do is like that, there is no constraint on [room number],[reservation date]

Answer (score 1):

Well, you're writing an [`INSTEAD OF`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175089%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) trigger - that means that the `INSERT` to the `reservation` won't happen unless you write one in your trigger - you need to write a new `INSERT` statement inside the trigger.

I'm not going to attempt to write the corrected version for you, because there are other issues related to multi-row inserts - `inserted` can contain multiple rows.

This means that a) You shouldn't do `= (select x from inserted)` because that subquery may return multiple values and you'll get a runtime error. And b) You may have a situation where *some* of the rows are valid, and *some* are invalid. I'm not sure how you would want to break that issue down, so that's why I'm not writing a replacement.

And finally, of course, (as mentioned in comments) this is a pointless exercise you've been set, since a `UNIQUE` constraint on the two columns would do the job far better than anything you write in a trigger.

Comment: see the modification I have made to my post

Comment: @SuSha - Looks like it should work or that it should produce an actual error message if it's not working. At a guess, it might not be working if you have an identity column - if that's the case, you have to give explicit column lists.

Comment: no it's not an identity column